# Checking Amazon Cognito Roles (Auth vs Unauth)

Tags: ios, authentication, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am new to using AWS as a backend for my iOS mobile app. I have set up all the roles and identiy pool needed. I have added the following code to my AppDelegate.m file:

```
// Starting AWS
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1 identityPoolId:@"IdentityPool"];

AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
```

What is the next step to see if I am authenticated or not? Trying to figue out iOS code to see what role I am in.

```
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

Answer (score 0):

Import service headers where you want to use AWS and then just try to make a call to AWS services.

```
AWSS3Transfermanager *transferManager = [AWSS3Transfermanager defaultS3TransferManager];
AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
uploadRequest.bucket = yourBucket;
uploadRequest.key = yourKey;
uploadRequest.body = yourDataURL;
uploadRequest.contentLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:fileSize];

[[transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
    // Do something with the response
    return nil;
}];
```